# Deleting all PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

i am creating a classic snake game where i need to shrink the board from the original size to smaller one as the level increases, what i got currently was that i managed to resize the board but the unused PictureBox are still there and unable to delete them. i am having trouble on how to delete and recall the method to recreate the PictureBox with new variable.

Really appreciate if there is someone who can help me solve my issue regarding PictureBox deletion/removal in C#. Here are some parts of the source code for my project. For Viewing the whole source code, can request from me directly.

Here where placed my code for the board to recreate/refresh.

```
private void gotoNextLevel(int nextLevel)
    {
        mode = "REST";
        mySnake = new Snake(mainBoard); //Brand new snake with length 1
        apples = new Rewards(nextLevel, mainBoard); //<--- Generate 5 apples
    }
```

Here is how i create my board for the game.

```
int maxRow = 10, maxCol = 20;       //Max 10 rows, and 20 columns in the board
    int squareSize = 30;                //Each square is 30px by 30px

    PictureBox[,] squares;

    public Board(Form mainForm)
    {
        squares = new PictureBox[maxRow, maxCol];
        for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
            {
                squares[row, col] = new PictureBox();
                squares[row, col].Location = new Point(col * squareSize, row * squareSize);
                squares[row, col].Height = squareSize;
                squares[row, col].Width = squareSize;
                squares[row, col].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                squares[row, col].BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                squares[row, col].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

                mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Controls.Add(squares[row, col]);
            }
        }
        mainForm.Controls["controlPanel"].Location = new Point(mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Location.X, mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Location.Y + mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Height + 20);
    }
```

Here is the refresh method.

```
private void refresh(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        mySnake.move(mode); //Move the snake based on mode
        modeLBL.Text = mode;

        mainBoard.draw();
        apples.draw();  //<----- draw apples
        mySnake.draw();

        //increment the duration by amount of time that has passed
        //this method is called every speed millisecond
        duration += speed;
        timerLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(duration / 1000); //Show time passed


        //Check if snke is biting itself. If so, call GameOver.
        if (mySnake.checkEatItself() == true)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (apples.checkIFSnakeHeadEatApple( mySnake.getHeadPosition()) == true)
        {
            score += apples.eatAppleAtPostion(mySnake.getHeadPosition());

            scoreLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(score);


            if (apples.noMoreApples() == true)
            {
                clock.Stop();
                level++;
                levelLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(level);
                gotoNextLevel(level);
                MessageBox.Show("Press the start button to go to Level " + level, "Congrats");
            }
            else
            {
                //Length the snake and continue with the Game
                mySnake.extendBody();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: clear the `Controls` collection of the boardPanel: `boardPanel.Controls.Clear();` will remove all the picture boxes.

Comment: You are making a common mistake with events.  Instead of using the arguments in the event refresh you are accessing the objects on the view directly.   You should be using MyObject.  Isn't is better to shrink the size of the current pictureboxes than create new ones?

Comment: after i use "boardPanel.Controls.Clear();" suggeested by dlatikay, the board correctly cleared everything but sadly it did not redraw my board with new values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: is the signature of refresh() generated by Visual Studio itself? If so, why don't you copy the body and put it in a new method without parameters because apparently you don't even use the ones in your current refresh() method.

Secondly: if you create that new method, you can create a method where you first clear the controls and then you call the redraw. I think it doesn't get redrawn because it was an event from a control which never gets called again because you just cleared all the controls.

And last but not least: if you have other controls than PictureBox but you only want to remove PictureBox you could use this:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is PictureBox)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(control);
    }
}
```